# How to get data of link “hits” count which are exist on SharePoint home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am new SharePoint environment. On SharePoint 2013 page,I want to get some analytics as number of hits for the link clicked in sharepoint site main pages.

For example, On the page, we have IT link, document library link, list webpart, latest news webpart, twitter webpart link are present on SharePoint main page. i want the count of hits for those links clicked on day in SharePoint. Please let me know.

Comment: Use `click` event of the link and for every click increment the counter in any list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure can you do it on spOnline but for on prem in the past I have utilized google analytics to give me this kind of insight. You need to include the google analytics code in your master page.

There are as well some alternative approaches check this:
http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/02/26/how-to-add-google-analytics-to-sharepoint-without-modifying-the-master-page/